# How To Get The Timestamp Of KinesisEvent.KinesisEventRecord

Tags: java, amazon-kinesis

I use this for loop to record Kinesis events.

```
for (KinesisEvent.KinesisEventRecord saver : event.getRecords()) {
            saver. ?       
        }
```

Forexample i can get eventId by `saver.getEventID`, name by `saver.getEventName()` etc. But how can i get the timestamp here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found it. You can get it via `getKinesis().getApproximateArrivalTimestamp()` function.

```
saver.getKinesis().getApproximateArrivalTimestamp();
```